# How does youtube player scale the progress/track bar?

Tags: html, css

I am wondering lets say for e.g. youtube's standard player width is 640px

```
var width = 640;
```

then we have a movie that goes for say **102** seconds

```
var length = 102px;
```

if the movie is then played, how does the trackbar know how to increment itself evenly when some divisions are fractions and are rounded either up or down depending on the fraction itself and/or browser that you are using.

so

```
6.4 = 1% of 640px
```

and

```
1.02 = 1% of 102px
```

but css rounds this to **6** and **1** accordingly if i am correct?
so wouldnt the player slowly lose precision?? and back to same question how is then calculated evenly somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't go for pixels here.

Current progress time / Total time * 100 = percentage of the progress

For example, the progress of a 2 minutes videos currently at 33 seconds is:

33/120*100 = 27.5%

```
.progress-bar {
  width: 100%; // Not really required actually
}

.progress {
  width: 27.5%
}
```

Comment: okay fair enough i thought about and thankyou for writing back fast :) i was thinking what if it is a fraction that leads to several decimal points like 27.453% can css still calculate this with precision?

Comment: e.g. 33 seconds into a 138 second video = 23.91304347826087

Comment: Each browser handle decimals a bit differently but it'd work, even with a lot of decimals. I've made multiple progress bars like this and never seen any bug related to calculation. Since you're gonna calculate it with JS you can keep only one or two decimals to be sure.